# Why is my KeyListener not reading keys?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keyboard

I am using a `JPanel` with `Graphics` to make a game. I have implemented a `KeyListener` and I have added it to my `JPanel`. I cannot get it to read the keycodes, however. I added a print statement that I assumed would print anytime a key was pushed, but none of the keys I press are returning codes. Here is my `JPanel` constructor:

```
public Game()
{
    super();
    JPanel mazepanel = new JPanel();
    this.add(mazepanel);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}
```

And here is my `KeyListener`.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent kb)
{
    System.out.println("Key pressed: " + kb.getKeyCode());
    if (kb.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        forward = true;
    }
    else if (kb.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        left = true;
    }
    else if (kb.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        right = true;
    }
    else if (kb.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        back = true;
    }
    else
    {

    }

    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Try `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` instead.

Comment: I have tried both, neither are doing anything.

Comment: This JPanel has to have focus too. If you want to avoid focus issues, you could use key bindings instead.

Comment: Game is a JPanel that is added to my frame in the main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JPanel is not focusable by default. Add

```
setFocusable(true);
```

to make it so.

Comment: The program is still not reading in any keys. I've set both, my panel and frame to be focusable.

Comment: Just the panel needs to be focusable. What did you add the listener to? The Frame or the Panel?

Comment: The listener was added to the panel alongside my `mouseListener`, which works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of a KeyListener to work off of:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyboardExample extends JPanel {

    public KeyboardExample() {
        KeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener();
        addKeyListener(listener);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
        KeyboardExample keyboardExample = new KeyboardExample();
        frame.add(keyboardExample);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("keyReleased="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
        }
    }
}
```

From http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game4.html